# Diffeomorphic intervals of $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $a , b$ and $c$ are real numbers with $a < b$. Can there be a smooth diffeomorphism between the semi-open interval $[a , b)$ and the unbounded closed interval $[c , +\infty)$? I know smooth diffeomorphism between the open interval $(a , b)$ and the unbounded open interval $(c , +\infty)$. Can this be extended? Any help please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take
$$h : (-\infty,b) \to (c-1,\infty), h(x) = c - 1 + \frac{b-a}{b-x} . $$
This is a smooth map with smooth inverse
$$g : (c-1,\infty) \to (-\infty,b), g(y) = b - \frac{b-a}{y - c +1} . $$
We have
$$h([a,b) ) = [c,\infty)$$
which proves that there is a smooth diffeomorphism between $[a,b)$ and $ [c,∞)$.

Comment: This is absolutely clear. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, without lost of generality, that $c>0$. The map
$$
x\to \frac{c(b-a)}{b-x}
$$
sends $[a,b)$ to $[c,+\infty)$.

You should be able to prove that it is indeed a diffeomorphism for manifolds with boundary.

Comment: Only for $c >0$.

Comment: you are true, I will edit